# Passing zip to a function gives "zip argument #2 must support iteration" error

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to pass zip() to a function but it gives "TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration " I don't know what is the reason.

Here is the code:

```
def translate(self,url,phrases):
        translator = Translator()
        translations_ar = translator.translate(phrases, dest='ar')
        translations_hy = translator.translate(phrases, dest='hy')
        translations_ms = translator.translate(phrases, dest='ms')
        translations_bg = translator.translate(phrases, dest='bg')
        # Chinese (Hong Kong SAR) changed with Chinese (Simplified) 
        translations_zh_cn_SAR = translator.translate(phrases, dest='zh-cn')
        # Chinese (Simplified)
        translations_zh_cn = translator.translate(phrases, dest='zh-cn')
        # Chinese (Singapore) changed with Chinese (Traditional)
        translations_zh_tw_singapore = translator.translate(phrases, dest='zh-tw')
        # Chinese (Traditional)
        translations_zh_tw = translator.translate(phrases, dest='zh-tw')
        translations_hr = translator.translate(phrases, dest='hr')
        translations_cs = translator.translate(phrases, dest='cs')
        translations_da = translator.translate(phrases, dest='da')
        translations_nl = translator.translate(phrases, dest='nl')
        translations_en_australia = translator.translate(phrases, dest='en')
        translations_en_uk = translator.translate(phrases, dest='en')
        translations_en_usa = translator.translate(phrases, dest='en')
        translations_et = translator.translate(phrases, dest='et')
        translations_fi = translator.translate(phrases, dest='fi')

        # Creating Array of Languages
        ar = [translation_ar.text for translation_ar in translations_ar]    
        hy = [translation_hy.text for translation_hy in translations_hy]    
        ms = [translation_ms.text for translation_ms in translations_ms]    
        bg = [translation_bg.text for translation_bg in translations_bg]
        zh_cn_SAR = [translation_zh_cn_SAR.text for translation_zh_cn_SAR in translations_zh_cn_SAR]    
        zh_cn = [translation_zh_cn.text for translation_zh_cn in translations_zh_cn]
        zh_tw_singapore = [translation_zh_tw_singapore.text for translation_zh_tw_singapore in translations_zh_tw_singapore]
        zh_tw = [translation_zh_tw.text for translation_zh_tw in translations_zh_tw]
        hr = [translation_hr.text for translation_hr in translations_hr]
        cs = [translation_cs.text for translation_cs in translations_cs]
        da = [translation_da.text for translation_da in translations_da]
        nl = [translation_nl.text for translation_nl in translations_nl]
        en_australia = [translation_en_australia.text for translation_en_australia in translations_en_australia]
        en_uk = [translation_en_uk.text for translation_en_uk in translations_en_uk]
        en_usa = [translation_en_usa.text for translation_en_usa in translations_en_usa]
        et = [translation_et.text for translation_et in translations_et]
        fi = [translation_fi.text for translation_fi in translations_fi]

        # zip arrays
        languages = zip(ar,hy,ms,bg,zh_cn_SAR,zh_cn,
        zh_tw_singapore,zh_tw,hr,cs,da,nl,en_australia,en_uk,en_usa,et,fi)   
        coderasha.write_csv(languages)
```

The code above is from another function and I have to pass "languages" to write_csv function:

```
    def write_csv(*args):
        with open('translations.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['Arabic', 'Armenian', 'Malaysia', 'Bulgarian', 'Chinese (Hong Kong SAR)', 
            'Chinese (Simplified)','Chinese (Singapore)','Chinese (Traditional)','Croatian', 'Czech',
            'Danish','Dutch','English (Australia)','English (UK)', 'English (USA)','Estonian','Finnish']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for lang in args:
                writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, lang)))
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank You!

Comment: Could you add the output of `print(ar)` and `print(hy)`?  If not all of these variables contain lists (or other iterables) of preferably the same length, you probably don't get what you would hope for.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `zip(fieldnames, [ar,hy,ms,bg,zh_cn_SAR,zh_cn, zh_tw_singapore,zh_tw,hr,cs,da,nl,en_australia,en_uk,en_usa,et,fi])` ?

Comment: they all are array for example print(en_uk) gives ["Test", "Test2"] and so on..

Comment: Yeah but it is not working without zipping it. How it is possible to pass all these arrays

Comment: `zip`  has nothing to do with compression to the zip format. `zip` goes through each of its arguments and creates a tuple of all the first elements of its arguments, then all the second elements, etc.

Comment: probably `hy` does not contain a valid list

Comment: No this code is working fine when I don't use "write_csv" function. The main problem is passing zip. So, there is no problem with `hy`

Comment: As @JohanC commented, can you please check the output of `print(type(hy))`?

Comment: Here is the output of `hy` -> `<class 'list'>`

Comment: `print(hy)` should show a real list.  How did you create `hy`?

Comment: I updated the code above take a  look. The all are real lists.